# Discrete solutions of boundary value problem with parameter.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the second order ordinary differential equation with one parameter $k$
$$(x-3)^7 ((x^2-4 x+3) f''(x)+2 x f'(x))+3456 k (3-2 x)^2 (x-1) x^2 f(x)=0, \quad 0 \leq  x \leq 1$$
and a set of boundary conditions
$$f(0)=0, \quad f'(0)=1, \quad f(1)=0.$$

Ignoring the last condition, the numerical solutions look like this:
[image: graph of f(x) for two k]

How do I (numerically) compute the parameters $k$ for which all three conditions hold?
I am not interested in the solutions, only in $k$.
What is the strategy here?
I tried to expand the ODE around $x=1$ and then set $f(1)=0$, yielding $f'(1)=0$. But that did not give me any information about $k$.

Comment: This is an eigenvalue problem, thus non-linear. Are you using a self-rolled solver method or a library with a bvp solver? You can add a DE $k'=0$ to the system so that the number of state components matches the number of boundary conditions.

Comment: Yes, solving the mixed BVP with $k'=0$ gives me the first $k$. But how to find the other? Eigenvalues seem to be the correct term here. Is there any way to tackle such a nonlinear problem numerically?

Comment: Your initial guess needs to be close to the solution, as with any non-linear system of equations, solvers are only guaranteed to work well locally. You could try to initialize the solution as $f(x)=\sin(m\pi x)/(m\pi)$ to get an appropriate amount of oscillation. This might work for a handful or two of eigenvalues, for larger $m$ the number of nodes of the resulting solution could have a more random relationship with $m$. A single-shooting method using the map from $k$ to $f(1)$ (with a bracketing root-finder) might work better in this case, the plot indicates such a method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping for an elegant algebraic solution to the eigenvalue problem, but the shooting method works very well. The roots of the map $k \rightarrow f_k(1)$ are nicely separated and easy to find using a bracketing method.

Comment: Yeah in this situation I would probably use a simple shooting method driven by a secant method for $k \mapsto f_k(1)$. But of course you can just search for eigenvalues/eigenfunctions and scale by $f'(0)$ to get the middle boundary condition to hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear [Sturm–Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) eigenvalue problem (if $f'(0) = 1$ condition is dropped, it is only needed to fix the unique solution).
$$
-\frac{d}{dx}\left[p(x) \frac{df}{dx}\right] + q(x) f(x) = \lambda w(x) f(x)
$$

First we need to scale the equation by $C(x)$ to form the $-\frac{d}{dx}\left[p(x) \frac{df}{dx}\right]$ term.
$$
C(x) (x-3)^7 ((x^2-4 x+3) f''(x)+2 x f'(x)) = -\frac{d}{dx}\left[p(x) \frac{df}{dx}\right]
$$
Eliminating $C(x)$ gives an equation for $p(x)$
$$
\frac{2x}{x^2-4 x+3} = 
\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} = (\log p(x))'
$$
By integrating we obtain
$$
p(x) = \frac{(x-3)^3}{x-1}
$$
and
$$
C(x) = \frac{-p(x)}{(x-3)^7 (x^2 - 4x + 3)} = -\frac{1}{(x-1)^2(x-3)^5}.
$$

$$-\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{(x-3)^3}{x-1} \frac{df}{dx}\right]
-\frac{3456}{(x-1)^2(x-3)^5} k (3-2 x)^2 (x-1) x^2 f(x)=0, \quad x \in [0,1]$$
Moving term with $k$ to the right we obtain the Sturm-Liouville form
$$
-\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{(x-3)^3}{x-1} \frac{df}{dx}\right]
=k \cdot \frac{3456}{(x-1)(x-3)^5} (3-2 x)^2 x^2 f(x)=0, \quad x \in [0,1]
$$
with parameters
$$
p(x) = \frac{(x-3)^3}{x-1}, \quad
q(x) = 0, \quad
w(x) = \frac{3456 x^2 (3-2 x)^2}{(x-1)(x-3)^5}.
$$

The idea of the numerical method is to introduce a regular grid on $x \in [0, 1]$ and approximate the equation with second order as
$$
-\frac{p(x_{i+1/2}) (f_{i+1} - f_i) - p(x_{i-1/2}) (f_i - f_{i-1})}{h^2}
+ q(x_i) f_i
= k w(x_i) f_i, \quad i = 1, \dots, N-1\\
f_0 = f_N = 0
$$
where $h = \frac{1}{N}$ and $x_j = jh$.

This results in an [(generalized) eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem)
$$
A \mathbf f = k W \mathbf f
$$
with tridiagonal matrix $A$ and diagonal matrix $W$, both symmetric and positive definite. The vector $\mathbf f = (f_1, f_2, \dots, f_{N-1})$. Nonzero elements of $A$ and $W$ are
$$
A_{i,i+1} = -p(x_{i+1/2})\\
A_{i,i-1} = -p(x_{i-1/2})\\
A_{i,i} = p(x_{i-1/2}) + p(x_{i+1/2}) + h^2 q(x_i)\\
W_{i,i} = h^2 w(x_i).
$$
The original eigenvalues $k$ can be approximated as eigenvalues of $W^{-1/2} A W^{-1/2}$.

The following *Mathematica* code implements the method

````
p[x_] = (3-x)^3/(1-x);
w[x_] = (3456x^2 (2x-3)^2)/(3-x)^5/(1-x);
q[x_] = 0;

M = 5000;
h = 1/M;
x[j_] = j h;

B = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] <= 1 :> 
    If[i == j, (p[x[i - 1/2]] + p[x[i + 1/2]] + h^2 q[x[i]])/(h^2 w[x[i]]), 
               -p[x[(i + j)/2]]/(h^2 Sqrt[w[x[i]] w[x[j]]])
    ], {M - 1, M - 1}];

Sort@Eigenvalues[N@B,-10]
// {4.68175, 16.7411, 36.1904, 63.0365, 97.2817, 138.927, 187.973,
244.42, 308.269, 379.519}
```
````

Comment: Wow, thank you for this detailed and instructive solution!

Answer (score 0):

I would have done the same.

If you use a CAS, it is very quickly done. The problem is that there are many solutions. Assuming that $k=\frac n {10}$ $n$ being a positive integer, the first solutions generate for $n$ the sequence
$$\{47,168,361,631,973,1389,1880,\cdots\}$$ which looks to be almost quadratic.

Having fitted these seven points, the next is predicted to be $2444$ which is correct (am I lucky ?).

Pay a lot of attention to @Lutz Lehmann's comment.

Comment: Thank you, this works indeed better (and faster) than I thought. I use Mathematica with a combination of ParametricNDSolve and FindRoot to find the first 100 values of $k$ under a second. The seemingly quadratic distribution is interesting but not surprising (This is about exited states of black holes).